# Is there a way to record a color shift with the actions tool in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, actions

I am trying to make a bunch (~100) of adjacent circles that fade through the colors of the rainbow. When creating the action I copy the red circle I made, paste it in place, nudge it over a bit, and then shift the blue color channel up 15 points (from 0 -> 15). When I play the action on the new circle I just pasted it doesn't shift the blue color channel up an additional 15 points starting from the 15 it was already at (15 -> 30). Instead seems like it resets the blue back down to zero and then shifts it back up to 15, so no change at all. When looking at the actions list for my newly created action it shows a series of "set color" actions starting with setting the blue to 1, then the next one sets the blue to 2, etc... Is there a way to make something like a "set color change" action that says "add 15 points to blue color channel", instead of setting the value channel to a specific number? Thanks for any tips =)

Comment: Unfortunately, I *think* any **relative** change to color isn't recordable as an action, you'd need scripting. There *are* ways to alter colors in a relative manner (i.e. Live Color/Recolor Artwork, HSV sliders), but actions don't record the alterations if my memory serves me correctly.

Comment: You could use a step blend to do it.  See example [here](https://imgur.com/a/fy1vSPS)

Comment: @BillyKerr I actually tried using the blend tool at first, but until I saw your comment I hadn't thought to try to "expand" the blended object so that the circles would become their own unique objects. Now that I've tried that this actually works perfectly for my situation. Thank you both for your help with my situation.